# Problem with enumerate and the order of images

Tags: graphics, enumerate

I use LaTeX occasionally and have had an issue with enumerate. The problem is with the ordering of the image with respect to the number. I included a screenshot of the problem below. Problem 1 is remedied with a period after \item. This works to force the image after the problem number. Below for problem 2 and 3 show how it looks without any characters after \item and with \phantom{}. As you can see I don't want the number of the problem after the image.

I can't seem to find a thread addressing this. Thank you very much!

Edit: Here is the code. If someone can tell me how to post it as I see code in other threads I'd really appreciate it!

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}



\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}



\begin{document}

Find the area of the following shapes
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item .
%
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{circle.png} 
\end{figure}
%
\item 
%
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{triangle.png} 
\end{figure}
%
\item  \phantom{}
%
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{trapezoid.png} 
\end{figure}
%
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From screenshot we can not see your code, even worse, we cant test it. So, please provide minimal but complete document, which we can compile and see your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* use the `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\ItemImage[2][]{%
    \hfill\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}\hfill~}
\begin{document}        
Some text before

\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
    \item \ItemImage[height=1cm]{tiger}
    \item \ItemImage[height=2cm]{tiger}
    \item \ItemImage[height=3cm]{tiger}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you Herbert! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering  
\definecolor{ttqqqq}{rgb}{0.2,0.,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(2.6266003997210037,2.514396631043019) rectangle (8.533772650288498,7.661239780052299);
\draw [color=ttqqqq] (5.609429951987758,5.10731382353633) circle (2.0743686540158026cm);
\draw [color=ttqqqq] (3.536912047343563,5.194920031607253)-- (7.681947856631956,5.019707615465408);
\draw (6.194298491647906,5.789660453139834) node[anchor=north west] {$8 cm$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ttqqqq] (5.609429951987758,5.10731382353633) circle (1.0pt);
\draw[color=ttqqqq] (5.667916805953773,5.555713037275775) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=ttqqqq] (3.536912047343563,5.194920031607253) circle (1.0pt);
\draw[color=ttqqqq] (3.19197332139248,5.302270003423046) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=ttqqqq] (7.681947856631956,5.019707615465408) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=ttqqqq] (7.812434784707649,5.302270003423046) node {$D$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Name of figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, was this supposed to be edited in to your other question? (PS you can apply the correct formatting by highlighting the code and pressing ctrl+k or the code sample button (fifth from the left, the one that looks like {} )

Comment: Yes, I think you (or someone else) fixed it. It should look normal now, thanks!

Comment: You can draw easier if you use Geogebra. We can get the code of which we drew. You can see more at https://nhcan.wordpress.com/2016/05/09/ve-hinh-trong-latex-bang-phan-mem-geogebra/

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't asking about drawing images. I use other programs for that. I can do it quicker. I was just trying to figure out why the ordering was off from what I had wanted.